# SSRS - DATEDIFF function requires 3 arguments

Tags: sql, reporting-services, datediff

I have a query in SQL that supports an `SSRS` report. The report generates this error code:

> `"DATEDIFF function requires 3 arguments"`

How do I correct this code?

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) Age,
        [Borrower   FirstName] + ' '
        + [Borrower LastName] BorrowerName,
        MonthlyIncome,
        DATENAME(MONTH,LoanDate) + ' ' 
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(YY,LoanDate)) FormatedReportMonth,
        LoanAmount,    
        [Purchase Price],

            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) < 25 
                            THEN '<=25'
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) between 25 and 35 
                            THEN '26-35'
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) between 36 and 45 
                            THEN '36-45'    
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) > 45 
                            THEN '46+' END AgeGroup,
            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) < 25 
                            THEN 1
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) between 25 and 35 
                            THEN 2
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) between 36 and 45 
                            THEN 3
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate) > 45 
                            THEN 4 END AgeGroupOrder    
            INTO        #Financials   
            FROM        dbo.Fact_Financials
```

Comment: What is your `@ReportDate` value ?? Can you give detail error ?

Comment: All the `DateDiff` functions in query is having `three` parameters. Are you sure this is the query that generated mentioned error

Comment: I am not sure what generated the error code. But I chose this part because it has DATEDIFF

Comment: @ReportDate datetime = '6/27/2013

Comment: The DATEDIFF expressions you have posted all appear to be written correctly, without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to say what else might be causing this error.

Comment: As an aside, your first expression is incorrect - `DATEDIFF(YY,d.[Date of Birth],@ReportDate)` won't give you someone's age. It *may* return their age or it may return a value that's too high by one, because `DATEDIFF` counts *transitions*. `DATEDIFF(YY,'20141231','20150101')` returns 1.

Comment: Can you post your complete query which are getting the data to the report dataset ?